# C# Select id int nested array by pair

Tags: c#, arrays

I have array1 like this

```
int[][] array1 = int[][] { int[]{0,7}, int[]{0,1}, int[]{0,6}, int[]{0,5}, int[]{1,7} }
```

and I have array2 like this:

```
int[][] array2 = int[][] { int[]{0,7},  int[]{0,5} }
```

How can I get index of element in array1 from elements in array2?

For instance:

```
int[] { 0, 7 } is id of 0 because it is first element  
int[] { 0, 5 } - id - 3 because it is fourth element in array1.
```

And `int[] { 0, 5 }` and `int[] { 5, 0 }` are the same members.

Should I simply loop `array1` and check members inside? Or there is smarter way of searching coincident items in `array1`?

Comment: Why not using Tuples? Or a class instead of n 2 dimensional arrays. You can use Array.IndexOf()? See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eddebat(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this if you want to get every id in `array1`.
You'll need to add a `using System.Linq;`

```
List<int> ids = new List<int>();
foreach (int[] arr in array2)
{
    var ordered = arr.OrderBy(x => x);
    ids.Add(Array.FindIndex(array1, a => a.OrderBy(x => x).SequenceEqual(ordered)));
}
```

Note that `ids` will contain `-1` where `arr` is not found in `array1`.
The arrays are being sorted before checking them for being equal, as you mentioned that `[5, 0]` is the same member as `[0, 5]`.